How to model a sequential/consecutive scheduling?
I have the following scenario:
A factory needs to receive some amount of products from different sources $S$, in this case, from farms. The farms need to discharge all their product in the farm but the discharge usually take more than one day. The period of discharge is defined by a list of days $D$.
My current model consist in two variables:
$x_{s,day} \in \mathbb{R}$, the amount of product from source (farm) discharged on day.
$y_{s,day}\in \{0,1\}$, related to $x$, that indicates if there is discharge on the day.
$b_{s,day}\in \{0,1\}$, that indicates if the discharge begins on day.
The discharge time $dt$ is known.
The way I thought:
I created constraints to define the "allowed days" sum, i.e., the period which the farm is allowed to perform the discharge starting at $b$.
The allowed days $ad$ is the range $[b,...,b+dt]$.
$$\sum_{ad}^{AD}y_{s,ad} = b_{s,d}\times dt \quad \forall s \in S,\forall d \in D$$
This will create sliding windows and would force the discharge to happen only in the specified range, if and only if the begin variable starts in day.
Take the case below as example:
BBB: 4 days; CCC: 5 days, GGG: 6 days.
Currently, I have:
Carrier1:
    2024-08-01: GGG
    2024-08-02: -----
    2024-08-03: GGG
    2024-08-04: CCC
    2024-08-05: BBB
    2024-08-06: CCC
    2024-08-07: BBB
    2024-08-08: CCC
    2024-08-09: BBB
    2024-08-10: GGG
    2024-08-11: GGG
    2024-08-12: CCC
    2024-08-13: GGG
    2024-08-14: BBB
    2024-08-15: CCC
    2024-08-16: GGG

But I wanted something like:
Carrier1:
    2024-08-01: GGG
    2024-08-02: GGG
    2024-08-03: GGG
    2024-08-04: GGG
    2024-08-05: GGG
    2024-08-06: GGG
    2024-08-07: BBB
    2024-08-08: BBB
    2024-08-09: BBB
    2024-08-10: BBB
    2024-08-11: CCC
    2024-08-12: CCC
    2024-08-13: CCC
    2024-08-14: CCC
    2024-08-15: CCC
    2024-08-16: -----

Consecutive and non-stop discharges.

Add the following constraints
$b_{s,d} \le y_{s,d} $
$y_{s,d-1}+y_{s,d+1} \le y_{s,d} + 1$
$\sum_{d = ad}^{AD} y_{s,d} = t_sb_{s,d} \quad \forall s \ \ \forall d \le AD$
